# Is there a curve that can not be parametrized with respect to arc-length?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, arc-length

Is there some curve that can not be parametrized with respect to arc-length? I know that if the curve is a non stop curve or restrictedly increasing then there is a one to one correspondence between the time's parameter $t$ and arc-length function's parameter $s$ then I can replace $t$ with $s$
. If my understanding was correct then by loosing this one to one correspondence between $s$ and $t$ I can not parametrize with respect to arc-length. Is there an example of such curve?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Several examples include the [Blancmange curve](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BlancmangeFunction.html) and the [Koch Snowflake](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KochSnowflake.html).

Comment: If the curve is not rectifiable then you can't define arc length, and thus you can't use it as a parameter. Read Wikipedia [Arc length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length) for details.